# Matrix multiplication of 3D matrix with rotation matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an `N x M x 3` matrix which represents `N*M` direction vectors. I want to multiply each direction vector with a 3 by 3 rotation matrix to get the vectors in a new coordinate system. How can I do this in MATLAB without using for loops?

Comment: Most probably you can just use `matrix-multiplication`. Have you tried it with loops yet? If so, share it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `reshape` to convert your `N x M x 3` matrix into an `(N*M) x 3`, then multiply by your rotation matrix `R` and then `reshape` the result back to be `N x M x 3`.

```
%// Create some example data and a rotation matrix
data = rand(5,4,3);
R = rand(3);

%// Apply rotation to 3D data matrix.
newdata = reshape(reshape(data, [], 3) * R, size(data));
```